# Is there a way to have something like SQL-Server's UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to have GUIDs instead of integers in my database (because users can share their databases with other users). In SQL Server I would do this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
   (Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID(),
   ...)
```

I could do this on the application side, but I was wondering if there is a way to implement it in the database itself.

Comment: There's an [official uuid extension module](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/file?name=ext/misc/uuid.c).

Comment: @Shawn How would I use that? I'm using SQLite Studio.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html

Comment: Thank you, I've finally figured it out.